# Xaml button Command does not fire

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, mobile

I'm using the CameraView from the XamarinCommunityToolKit. Why button command "Capture" does not fire when I click it? Is it because code is running in emulator and not in actual physical phone with a real camera?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
         x:Class="App2.Views.CapturePage">

<StackLayout>

    <xct:CameraView
            x:Name="cameraView"
            CaptureMode="Photo"
            FlashMode="Off"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            MediaCaptured="CameraView_MediaCaptured"
            OnAvailable="CameraView_OnAvailable"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

    <Button
                x:Name="doCameraThings"
                Command="{Binding CaptureCommand, Source={x:Reference cameraView}}"
                IsEnabled="True"
                Text="Capture" />
    
    <Image
                x:Name="previewPicture"
                Aspect="AspectFit"
                BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                HeightRequest="250"
                IsVisible="False" />

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class CaptureViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public Command CaptureCommand { get; }
   
    public CaptureViewModel()
    {
        CaptureCommand = new Command(CapturePageClicked);
    }

    private async void CapturePageClicked()
    {
        //Some code here
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you have `Source={x:Reference cameraView}`?  The Command is not defined in `cameraView`

Comment: I just copied it like that from the XamarinCommunityToolKit sample project. Here's what it's like in the sample as is: 

 <Button
                    x:Name="doCameraThings"
                    Command="{Binding ShutterCommand, Source={x:Reference cameraView}}"
                    IsEnabled="False"
                    Text="Start Recording" />

Comment: they are using "ShutterCommand" which is defined in the CameraView.

Comment: I see.. Unfortunately, the doco and sample are not clear on how to use this CameraView.

Answer (score 0):

From [Xamarin Community Toolkit CameraView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/cameraview), there is one Icommand ShutterCommand for CameraView, so you can binding ShutterCommand to Button.Command.

```
 <StackLayout>
        <xct:CameraView
            x:Name="cameraview"
            CaptureMode="Photo"
            FlashMode="On"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            MediaCaptured="cameraView_MediaCaptured"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            />
        <Button
            x:Name="doCameraThings"
            Command="{Binding ShutterCommand, Source={x:Reference cameraview}}"
            IsEnabled="True"
            Text="Capture" />
      
        <Image
            x:Name="previewPicture"
            Aspect="AspectFit"
            BackgroundColor="LightGray"
            HeightRequest="250"
            IsVisible="False" />
    </StackLayout>

public partial class Page6 : ContentPage
{
    public Page6()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
      
    }     

    private void cameraView_MediaCaptured(object sender, Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views.MediaCapturedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (cameraview.CaptureMode)
        {
            default:
            case CameraCaptureMode.Default:
            case CameraCaptureMode.Photo:
                previewPicture.IsVisible = true;
                previewPicture.Rotation = e.Rotation;
                previewPicture.Source = e.Image;
              
                break;
            case CameraCaptureMode.Video:
                previewPicture.IsVisible = false;
               
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

But you can also binding another command to Button.click in Viewmodel.

```
<xct:CameraView
            x:Name="cameraview"
            CaptureMode="Photo"
            FlashMode="On"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            MediaCaptured="cameraView_MediaCaptured"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            />
      
        <Button
            x:Name="doCameraThings"
            Command="{Binding CaptureCommand}"
            IsEnabled="True"
            Text="Capture" />

        <Image
            x:Name="previewPicture"
            Aspect="AspectFit"
            BackgroundColor="LightGray"
            HeightRequest="250"
            IsVisible="False" />

  public class CaptureViewModel
{
    public Command CaptureCommand { get; }
    public CaptureViewModel()
    {
        CaptureCommand = new Command(CapturePageClicked);
    }
    private async void CapturePageClicked()
    {

        //Some code here
    }
}
```

Binding ViewModel to current page BindingContext

```
 public Page6()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new CaptureViewModel();
        
    }
```

simple sample about CameraView, you can take a look:

https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/main/samples/XCT.Sample/Pages/Views/CameraViewPage.xaml